# synchronizing data between DB2 to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, db2

I am trying to look for some help in getting data synchronized live from DB2 to SQL Server and vice versa. Why do I need this, because of our constraints we are forced to go this route where some applications are in SQL Server and some are in DB2. Now they have common tables. So when apps on SQL Server side update/insert/delete, we should get it on the DB2 side. Similarly when apps on the DB2 side update/insert/delete we should get it in SQL Server.

I found a few ways in doing it, but I'm not sure if I am doing it right.

1. Use triggers through linked servers. (but I am getting this  **The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server  does not support the required transaction interface.**)
2. use SSIS
3. replication

My Trigger:- 
This is how I am implementing my TriggerUSE [MyDatabase]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
go

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTrigger] ON [dbo].[MySQLTable] 
    FOR update 
AS 
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION

DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @VAR char(2),@Cat varchar(2)
SELECT  @VAR = 'TT'
SELECT @TSQL =**'UPDATE oq SET    oq.STATUS = p.STATUS FROM   OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,''select * from DB2Database.dbo.MyDb2Table WHERE ID = ''''' + @VAR + ''''' and Num= 1 and Seq= 1'') oq INNER JOIN dbo.MySQLTable p ON oq.ID collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  = p.ID  and oq.NUM  = p.NUM and oq.SEQ  = p.SEQ  '**

EXEC (@TSQL)

COMMIT TRANSACTION

Comment: If you want help with #1 you need to provide details/code.

Comment: Dan, Added my trigger above. Do you think Trigger is the best way to approach the problem I have.